# Session time out implementation issue with back button on title bar

Tags: android, session, back-button, motionevent

I have implemented a session time out feature in my application

- When ever user is not active on my app, leaves the app running for about 3 min, it will populate a dialog to confirm the PIN number to proceed.
- This works fine but when the user clicks the BACK button on title bar in any activity(if the session is timed out - 3min), the app will show the dialog as a flash and goes back to previous activity.
- When the back button is clicked and session is timed out. I want the app to populate the dialog asking for pin but not move back to the previous activity until the pin matches.
- I tried looking for information to control the BACK button on the title bar. When the user clicks back button it should first check if the session is timed out and then proceed, but could not find any information.
- To achieve this I am using "dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)", Is it a good approach to check the time every time the user clicks on the app?
- If you could suggest some solution or any different approach to achieve this.

  /**
     Method to check the idle time of the application and display a dialog for
     pin verification

  */

  ```
      public void checkLastLoggedInTime() {

         if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - lastLoggedIn) / 1000 >= 300) {

             if (pinVerficationDialogPopedUp == false) {
                 //pops up the pin dialog
                 pinVerificationDialog();
             }
             } else {
                lastLoggedIn = System.currentTimeMillis();
             }
        }
  ```

  On every activity I implemented "dispatchTouchEvent()" and "onResume()" to check the session time out

  ```
      @Override
      public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
      if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
          // check the idle time
          try{
          Utility utilityObj = new Utility(this);
          utilityObj.checkLastLoggedInTime();
          }catch(Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
      return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
      }

      @Override
      protected void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
      // check the idle time
      try{
           Utility utilityObj = new Utility(this);
           utilityObj.checkLastLoggedInTime();
      }catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      }
  ```

  Your suggestions are much appreciated, Thank you in advance.